# How to use CMake with cygwin/mingw toolchain?

Tags: cmake, cygwin, mingw

What is the current process to use the mingw toolchain that is included with cygwin?

There use to be a -mno-cygwin option used with gcc.

The mingw versions have x86_64-w64-mingw32- or i686-w64-mingw32- added to their exe names.  Currently I just use these directly but I want to use cmake.

Cygwin also includes cmake.  How would I configure it to use the mingw toolset that is included with cygwin?  I also see some Qt5 *.cmake modules included in the Qt5 libraries for mingw.

Thanks.

Comment: No time to write a detailed answer, but the right solution is to create a cmake toolchain file and use it with  cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=... I just blogged about it here: http://smallissimo.blogspot.com/2021/02/cross-compiling-for-windows-target-with.html See also https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/cross_compiling/Mingw or https://gist.github.com/peterspackman/8cf73f7f12ba270aa8192d6911972fe8

Answer (score 1):

I've found a temporary workaround.  Just define these two environment variables:

```
set CC=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
set CXX=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
```

Define them before running the cmake that is included with cygwin.
Seems to work.

Comment: `CXX` should be set to `g++.exe`. With it set to `gcc`, I got "undefined reference" linker errors.

Comment: CXX should be g++, copy and paste error.  Someone fixed it.